# Java scoket DataInput doesn't read until buffer is full

Tags: java, file, sockets, networking, stream

I am making a file-sharing program for my LAN, and I'm sending data from client 1, into a server, that sends it to client 2.

The problem is, that my buffer size is 8192 bytes, and when I read a certain file, if it isn't perfectly divisible with the buffer size, the remainder of it will get stuck in the stream until another file is added, and the amount of data finally reaches the buffer size.

Is there a way to stop read() from blocking until the threshold is reached? Or just a way around the entire situation?

I know that all of the batches are sent, because I counted them, and when counting how many batches were processed by the server, it's one less than received.

Here's the server code:

```
public void processFile(DataInputStream input){
        try {
            int iteration = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(buffer)) > 0){
                input.read(buffer);
                for (DataOutputStream output : outputs)
                    output.write(buffer, 0, count);
                System.out.println("batch n. " + iteration);
                iteration++;    
            }

            System.out.println("DONE");
        } catch (IOException io){
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Client code (for sending, receiving is pretty much the same as the server):

```
                fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
                byte[] fileName = file.getName().getBytes();
                // dataOutput.write(fileName, 0, fileName.length);
                System.out.println(new String(fileName));
                while ((count = fileInput.read(buffer)) > 0){
                    System.out.println("Send n. " + iteration);

                    dataOutput.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    iteration++;
                }
                System.out.println("finished sending");
                fileInput.close();
```

Comment: If you leave the socket output stream open for later use you should call flush() after each file.

Comment: @vanje  does flush() fill the remainder of the buffer? because there is no data left to pass from client 1, so the server doesn't get the chance to execute anything until it reads what it needs.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush--